# Finding Interfaces

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

Supposing i have a dictionary that I have created using defaultdict like this one(many hundred points long):

```
L [(32.992, 22.861, 29.486, 'TYR'), (32.613, 26.653, 29.569, 'VAL'), (30.029, 28.873,     27.872, 'LEU')
A [(1.719, -25.217, 8.694, 'PRO'), (2.934, -21.997, 7.084, 'SER'), (5.35, -19.779, 8.986, 'VAL')
H [(-0.511, 19.577, 27.422, 'GLU'), (2.336, 18.416, 29.649, 'VAL'), (2.65, 19.35, 33.322, 'GLN')
```

I then want to loop over every value in each key and check the distance from that value to every other residue under the other keys. I know how to check the distance using a simple formula, but I am having problems getting the loop to work properly. Ideally it would check each point in L against each point in A and H and then move on to checking each_value in A against L and H etc...

I have tried simple comprehensions but I always get only one chain to check one other chain before it finishes. Any help is appreciated.

I am extracting coordinates from a PDB file like this:

```
xyz = []

for line in pdb_file:
    if line.startswith("ATOM"):
        # get x, y, z coordinates for Cas
        chainid = str((line[20:23].strip()))
        atomid = str((line[16:20].strip()))
        pdbresn= int(line[23:26].strip())
        x = float(line[30:38].strip())
        y = float(line[38:46].strip())
        z = float(line[46:54].strip())
        if line[12:16].strip() == "CA":
            xyz.append((chainid,x,y,z,atomid))
```

and then putting it into a dictionary like this:

```
d = defaultdict(list)
for c,x,y,z,cid in xyz:
    d[c].append((x,y,z,cid))
```

giving this when i `print(d):

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'L': [(32.992, 22.861, 29.486, 'TYR'), (32.613, 26.653, 29.569, 'VAL'), (30.029, 28.873, 27.872, 'LEU')],'H': [(30.254, 32.655, 27.849, 'THR'), (27.487, 35.089, 27.0, 'GLN'), (27.343, 38.9, 27.424, 'PRO')], 'A': [(25.621, 40.067, 30.641, 'PRO'), (23.161, 42.327, 28.82, 'SER'), (22.086, 43.358, 25.326, 'VAL'), (20.081, 46.519, 24.785, 'SER'), (18.23, 46.826, 21.488, 'VAL')]})
```

Comment: What you've shown us is not a dictionary, or anything else. Please give us your actual data. Is it `{'L': [(…blah blah…)], 'A': […etc.}`? Or something different?

Comment: Also, "I am having problems getting the loop to work properly" doesn't help us debug your code or offer suggestions. Show us what you tried, what you expected or wanted it to do, and what it's actually doing instead, and we can help.

Comment: Also, why is this tagged pdb?

Comment: This is tagged PDB because I am working with a PDB file. It is rather hard to show my data structure because it is a large amount of data.

Comment: Hover over or click on the pdb tag: "Pdb is the Python debugger." Meanwhile, if your data structure is too large to show, create a stripped-down version that demonstrates the same question without being too large to show. See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for more details.

Comment: More importantly… Have I actually guessed correctly what you want to do? If not, can you tell where I guessed wrong, and figure out how to explain it better? I'm assuming you're here because you want an actual answer to your question, not to learn more about StackOverflow, right? So focus on the important stuff first.

Comment: I will try to explain it in a different way. Imagine 3 objects that are in close proximity to one another. The 3 keys are are the names of the 3 objects and the values associated with each key are the coordinates that represent the position of the objects. I am trying to find the points in each object that are within a certain distance of any point in each of the other objects.

Comment: After looking at itertools I do believe that you have guessed correctly what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to take a guess at what you want here.

You have a dictionary, something like this:

```
{'L': [(32.992, 22.861, 29.486, 'TYR'), (32.613, 26.653, 29.569, 'VAL'), (30.029, 28.873,     27.872, 'LEU')],
 'A': [(1.719, -25.217, 8.694, 'PRO'), (2.934, -21.997, 7.084, 'SER'), (5.35, -19.779, 8.986, 'VAL')],
 'H': [(-0.511, 19.577, 27.422, 'GLU'), (2.336, 18.416, 29.649, 'VAL'), (2.65, 19.35, 33.322, 'GLN')]}
```

What you want is something like this pseudocode:

```
for each list in the dictionary's values:
    for each of the other two lists:
        for each element in the first list:
            for each element in the other list:
                do something with the distance between the two elements.
```

In this case, "each of the other two lists" is pretty simple, because there are only 3… but in general, it's simpler to do this as:

```
for each pair of lists in the dictionary's values:
    for each pair of elements from the cartesian product of the two lists:
        do something with the distance between the two elements
```

And you can translate that directly to Python:

```
from itertools import permutations, product, chain

for lst1, lst2 in permutations(d.values(), 2):
    for e1, e2 in chain.from_iterable(product(lst1, lst2)):
        do_something_with(dist(e1, e2))
```

If you just want to get collect those distances into a list with as a comprehension, that's easy:

```
distances = [dist(e1, e2) for lst1, lst2 in permutations(d.values(), 2)
             for e1, e2 in chain.from_iterable(product(lst1, lst2))]
```

However, I think it might be more readable like this:

```
list_pairs = permutations(d.values(), 2)
item_pairs = chain.from_iterable(product(lst1, lst2) for lst1, lst2 in list_pairs)
distances = [dist(e1, e2) for e1, e2 in item_pairs]
```

Comment: This was originally a long list like this:
    
[('A', 1.719, -25.217, 8.694, 'PRO'), ('A', 2.934, -21.997, 7.084, 'SER'), ('A', 5.35, -19.779, 8.986, 'VAL')

I put them into a dictionary using defaultdict so that it consolidated each point under a key that was the first part of each sublist. When I print them by key they show up as in my original post.

Comment: @pioneer903: You _still_ haven't described what your data structure looks like. I have to guess what you mean by "print them by key", and then figure out what structure would come out the way you've shown given my guess. But meanwhile, I don't think that really changes things—the lists are `d.values()` instead of `L, A, H`, but what you want to do with them is the same. And I still have no idea whether I correctly guessed what you want to do with them.